# confusion of halting problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computability

Show that the following problem is solvable.Given two programs with their inputs and the knowledge that exactly one of them halts, determine which halts.

lets P be program that determine one of the program will be halted.

```
P(Program x,Program y){

    if(x will be halted)

          then return 1;

    else

           then return 2;
}
```

since we know that exactly one of them will be halted,if 1 then program x will be halted.Otherwiae program y will be halted.

then we construct a new program call D

```
D(X,Y){

     if(P(X,Y) == 2)

         D will halt;

      else

         while(1)//D will not halt;

  }
```

lets S be aritbrary program.

So if we have D(D,S)

if D will halt then D will not halt

if D will not halt then D will halt

It impiles a contradiction same as halting problem.

But the question stated that it is solvable.

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$

Comment: Even more important than using $\LaTeX$ here is to make all code be formatted as such. Currently only the indented lines are formatted as code. Indent all lines with at least 4 spaces (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code)).

Comment: I don't understand your proposed counterexample.  The way I understand $P$ it must also take an input argument (since any program may halt for some inputs but not for others).  But then which input argument do you intend for your example?

Comment: @lulu i will have D and S be my argument,S is program and D is a program too,if program D detect '2' and it will not halt,otherwise, it will be halted.So we have D(P(D,S)), the program P will run first,if program D will halt,program P will return 1,then program D receive 1 and D will not halt and cause the contrdiciton since D is halted and not halt in the same time.

Comment: I don't understand.  $D$ halts on some inputs but not on others, so what does it mean  to evaluate $P(D, S)$?  I could understand that if $P$ also considers a fixed input, but not otherwise.

Comment: The answer is extremely simple : We just run both programs. Since we know that one of them will halt we simply wait until one them halt (which can only take a finite amount of time) , and we have solved the problem. Something must be wrong with the counterexample.

Comment: @lulu sorry,I don't got it,can you explain more in detail

Comment: As your example indicates, it doesn't make sense to say "$D$ halts" or "$D$ doesn't halt".  The reality is that $D$ halts for some inputs but not for others.  If you meant that $P$ only detects wether a program halts for all inputs, then it can't accept $D$ as an input.  Otherwise you need to say which underlying  input you are considering (or inputs, I guess, as the two programs might take different inputs).

Comment: D can took itself be the input.P is a program that detect two programs which one will be halted,given that exactly one program will be halted.

Comment: Once again:  It doesn't make sense to ask "which one will be halted" unless you say which input(s) the two programs are taking.  $D$, in particular, halts sometimes and not other times depending on the inputs.

Comment: D taking D as input,S taking S as input.No matter  D halt or not.It always cause to the contradiction.

Comment: D(P(D,S)), supposed D take itself as the input,if D will be halted,P will return 1,D will not halt.If D will not halt,P will return 2,so D will halt.

Comment: You are just repeating yourself, you aren't responding to my point.  $D$ can't take itself as an input, at least not the way you wrote it.  Your $D$ takes $n\in \{1,2\}$ as inputs.  So, which of $1,2$ does $P$ consider?

Comment: @lulu Thanks,it is was my mistake, I take 2 as D input,then D will halt,P will return 1,D will not halt,it always casue the contradiction

Comment: @Peter Why we can construct counterexample in halting problem but not that problem?

Comment: I am not an expert in turing machines. $(1)$ It might be that we , strictly speaking , need two machines for my approach. $(2)$ My approach does not decide algorithmically which machine halts (this is probably not possible , hence your construction can be valid) , but it uses the information that one of the machines will eventually halt. $(3)$ Simply running a machine is however no solution, if we want to decide whether a given turing machine halts, since we cannot wait forever.

Comment: Once again:  There is no contradiction.  You have two programs according to which input you take.  $D[1]$ does not halt, $D[2]$ does.  Let's say $S$ is the opposite, so $S[1]$ halts but $S[2]$ does not.  Then $P(D[1],S[1])=2$ since $2$.  Since $S[1]$ is the unique argument that halts.  But then  $D[P(D[1],S[1])]=D[2]$ which does not halt.  So what?  All that says is that $D$ halts for some inputs but not for others, which we already knew.

Comment: @Peter  I expect that your program suffers from the same sort of paradox that plaques [Hypergame](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2006-2007/Games/hypergame.html).  After all, if your program which can call any halting game as one argument halts itself, then it can call itself so we can produce a loop.

Comment: @lulu  Thanks for your detailed explanation.  But why D[1} D[2}  occur in the same time doesn't imply contradiction?It is just like the halting problem,what it is different from contradiction from halting problem.halting problem also claimed D[1]D[2]cannot occur in the same time.

Comment: @lulu The algorithmical approach will probably fail. But a universal turing machine can simulate every given machine (including the input) and will halt if and only if the given machine halts. The only question is whether we need two of such universal machines. Whether the machines halt for every input does not matter for the given task.

Comment: @Peter There is no difference between a finite collection of universal machines and a single one.  A single machine can emulate a pair.

Comment: Then, we will see in a finite amounf of time , which machine halts. Hence the problem is decidable.

Comment: That's the Hypergame error.  If calling a finite game is itself finite then  that game can call itself.

Comment: Should say:  I think the problem is ill posed, since we can not know in advance which programs halt and which do not.  What does the supposed universal program do if you call it with inappropriate inputs?

Comment: @lulu OK, then what about just letting the two machines run (without an emulation) ? This is not really an algorihtm, but will always leads to a result since we know that one machine halts.

Comment: @Peter Like I say, I think that speaking of the collection of pairs of programs, exactly one of which halts, is intrinsically problematic.  Determining whether a pair of programs belongs to that collection is, of course, undecidable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110297/discussion-between-peter-and-lulu).